# Static product page URL with category

Tags: url

I'm looking for solution of how to make the product always have a static URL with category name, no matter from what category I entered. I want URL to always look like this:

```
http://example.com/category/subcategory/product-name
```

But instead, I'm getting a bunch of URL's:

```
http://example.com/product-name
http://example.com/category/product-name
http://example.com/category/subcategory/product-name
```

I know that I can add canonical URL tag, but it's not an option in this case.

Thank you, any suggestions about from where should I start are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution http://www.mikesmullin.com/development/use-categories-product-urls-magento-seo-without-duplicate-content/

Basically, all what's required is to remove this part:

```
->where('category_id = ? OR category_id IS NULL', $this->_urlRewriteCategory)
```

From `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` (around line 1100, in function `_addUrlRewrite`).

Of course you shouldn't modify core files directly and overwrite it from your module.

Comment: In Magento CE-1.9.0 the code in `.../Collection.php` no longer matches what you have put. Have you got an updated solution? I am after similar but instead only want the `http://example.com/product-name` version not any including categories