# Force only category URL

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url

Currently my Magento store (ce-1.9.0) has all its products in parent folders. For each product it will have 2 urls:

1. From the Homepage = `mysite.com/product-page`
2. From the Category Page = `mysite.com/category/product-page`

My problem is I need to only have the category url and not the URL straight from the homepage.

I know I can do the opposite (don't have category version, only homepage) by setting the `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` option to No in the admin system but there is no way of doing what i want.

I came across [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/static-product-page-url-with-category) when searching the Q&A's but the link it points to is no longer valid and it looks like it was a previous magento version (1.5) not for the one i am using - ce-1.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, realize two things:

- Google cares about URLs
- Users don't care about URLs

So if you're trying to cater to the first, and not the second, then we have two options:

- Enabling canonical URLs for Categories

OR

- Disabling the category path URLs setting.

Here's how to do both:

### Enable canonical URLs

In `System > Config > Catalog > SEO` enable this setting:

[image]

### Disable category path in URLs:

[image]

Comment: I need to stop the first url completely from being built rather than relying on canonical tags etc. The reason being is are site is very very big and we need to only have 1 url as although currently only 1 version gets indexed in google, they are still being crawled so our crawl budget is being wasted

Comment: Well then the second option is what you need. (Honestly I think you need both) - turn that option to NO.

Comment: But although the second option gives me only 1 url, it is not the one i need. I need to only have `mysite.com/category/product-page` rather than `mysite.com/product-page`

Comment: This is the reason canonicals exist. You will have to set the canonical to avoid duplicate content penalties. Take the raw Magento URL without category and create htaccess (or equiv) rewrites for all previous URLs to 301 all of your content to it.

Comment: I have had this issue in the past, honestly, but my requirement was to have all products prefaced with `products/`... aside from shoving all the products into a subfolder called `products/` (which created other issues with SEO) we learned to just trust how Magento was creating urls and use the rel=canonical as it is intended to work.

Comment: Have gone with this concept like you said in the end, thank you