# Remove Multiple Product URL Rewrites

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, url, url-rewrite

In my CE-1.9.0 store my products currently create the following url rewrites:

```
http://example.com/product-name
http://example.com/category/product-name
http://example.com/another-category/subcategory/product-name
```

However in my store I want to be able to stop creating the rewrites for the category versions. I have `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to `No` so these extra rewrites are unnecessary. Plus my store has around 500,000 products and counting so these extra url's are taking up a lot of space in the core_url_rewrite` table.

So my aim is to only be left with these versions:

```
http://example.com/product-name
```

If I truncate the core_url_rewrite table and reindex then only these versions get created so it is only when new products are created. My catalog is so large so I cannot keep truncated and rebuilding the table from scratch as the rebuilding takes several hours.

With help from [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/static-product-page-url-with-category/4168#4168) I have found the file that is responsible for creating the rewrites when a product is created. It is:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
```

However the answer is no longer valid as the code has changed in the core file.

In this file on line #538 there is the `_afterLoad` function it is the line

```
$this->_addUrlRewrite($this->_urlRewriteCategory);
```

And this function `_addUrlRewrite` however i've tried changing a lot inside this function but have had no luck. The function in full is:

```
protected function _addUrlRewrite()
{
    $urlRewrites = null;
    if ($this->_cacheConf) {
        if (!($urlRewrites = Mage::app()->loadCache($this->_cacheConf['prefix'] . 'urlrewrite'))) {
            $urlRewrites = null;
        } else {
            $urlRewrites = unserialize($urlRewrites);
        }
    }

    if (!$urlRewrites) {
        $productIds = array();
        foreach($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $productIds[] = $item->getEntityId();
        }
        if (!count($productIds)) {
            return;
        }

        $select = $this->_factory->getProductUrlRewriteHelper()
            ->getTableSelect($productIds, $this->_urlRewriteCategory, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        $urlRewrites = array();
        foreach ($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select) as $row) {
            if (!isset($urlRewrites[$row['product_id']])) {
                $urlRewrites[$row['product_id']] = $row['request_path'];
            }
        }

        if ($this->_cacheConf) {
            Mage::app()->saveCache(
                serialize($urlRewrites),
                $this->_cacheConf['prefix'] . 'urlrewrite',
                array_merge($this->_cacheConf['tags'], array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::CACHE_TAG)),
                $this->_cacheLifetime
            );
        }
    }

    foreach($this->getItems() as $item) {
        if (empty($this->_urlRewriteCategory)) {
            $item->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }
        if (isset($urlRewrites[$item->getEntityId()])) {
            $item->setData('request_path', $urlRewrites[$item->getEntityId()]);
        } else {
            $item->setData('request_path', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url`.

In your config.xml:

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <url>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Url</url>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

Create a new Modle `Resource/Url.php` in your Module and override the method `saveRewrite()`

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Url
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url
{
    public function saveRewrite($rewriteData, $rewrite)
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_URL_USE_CATEGORY)
            && isset($rewriteData['category_id'])
            && $rewriteData['category_id'] > 0
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        return parent::saveRewrite($rewriteData, $rewrite);
    }
}
```

You have to truncate the core_url_rewrite and start the `catalog_url` reindex. The code doesn't affect the Category URL Rewrite and works with product save and reindex.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed